# Do the partial derivative and the creation operator commute?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory

Does the partial derivative operator $\partial^\mu$ commute with the creation operator $\hat{a}^\dagger$? My notation here is
\begin{equation}
a_{\boldsymbol{p} }^\dagger|0\rangle=| \boldsymbol{p}\rangle
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\partial^\mu=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}.
\end{equation}
How would I go about proving that it does or doesn't?

Comment: Well, you can always write the partial derivative in terms of the momentum operator.  Then you can express the momentum operator as creation and annihilation operators and find out for yourself.

Comment: Your question is ill-defined because $\partial^\mu$ is *not* an operator on the space of states. It's a derivative operator acting on (operator-valued) fields, not on states.

Comment: So I can't ask them to commute because they act on different things? If, then, I were to find myself operating with $\partial^\mu$ on an expression with creation and annihilation operators I should just move $\partial^\mu$ past them, for example $\partial^\mu(\hat{a}^\dagger e^{ip\cdot x})=\hat{a}^\dagger\partial^\mu e^{ip\cdot x}$?

Answer (score 2):

Well you know that,

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} = \frac{i}{\hbar}\hat{p} = \frac{i}{\hbar}i\sqrt{\frac{\hbar m\omega}{2}}(a^\dagger-a) $$

then we can say,

$$[\frac{\partial}{\partial x},a^\dagger] = c[a^\dagger-a,a^\dagger] = -c[a,a^\dagger]$$

Comment: The $*$ is confusing. For multiplication just use either nothing or $\cdot$. The $*$ is almost never used for multiplication.

Comment: Please notice that $\partial_x$ is *not* equivalent to the momentum operator. It is instead the *representation* of the momentum operator on the position basis.